# Print only one match per line

Tags: regex, awk, grep, sh

I have a log like this

```
3>DirectMicrophone.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DirectSoundCaptureEnumerateW@8 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall DirectMicrophoneManager::getDevices(void)" (?getDevices@DirectMicrophoneManager@@AAEXXZ)
3>DirectMicrophone.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DSDEVID_DefaultVoiceCapture
3>DirectMicrophone.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IDirectSoundCapture
3>DirectSoundPlayer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DirectSoundCreate@12 referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall DirectSoer::CreateDirBuffers(void)" (?CreateDirBuffers@DirPlayer@@AAE_NXZ)
libmodule-text.lib(CTS_Support.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _delete "void __cdecl operator delete(void *)" (??3@YAXPAX@Z)
3>rtmfp_interface.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CIcos
```

I just want to extract the symbols highlighted in the log. There are two approaches for the same

1. Print the first word per line after "external symbol"
2. print the first word per line starting with "_"

I tried the second approach using the script

```
egrep -o "(\s(_\S+))" <log_file>
```

but it prints all the words starting with "_" and not just the first matching word in the line. 
I want to know how to make the script print only the first matching word and not all the matching words in the line.

Expected output:

```
_DirectSoundCaptureEnumerateW@8
_DSDEVID_DefaultVoiceCapture
_IID_IDirectSoundCapture
_DirectSoundCreate@12
_delete
__CIcos
```

Comment: What is your expected output ? Do you want to output including the asterisks and `@` ?

Comment: did you want to mention the string `external symbol` in your regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep -oP` command:

```
grep -oP '^[^:]+:[^_]+\K(\S+)' logs
_DirectSoundCaptureEnumerateW@8
_DSDEVID_DefaultVoiceCapture
_IID_IDirectSoundCapture
_DirectSoundCreate@12
_delete
__CIcos
```

OR using `awk`:

```
awk -F '^[^:]+:[^_]+' '{sub(/ .*$/, "", $2); print $2}' logs
```

Comment: I tested both on OSX awk and gnu-awk to produce this output.

Comment: I'm on GNU Awk 3.1.5, and it just prints blank lines, pretty sure it isn't liking the multi character FS. Actually its fine with the multichar FS, it seems that they are $3 when using that FS.

Comment: I have `GNU Awk 4.1.0` and OSX `awk version 20070501`

Comment: That awk script will function exactly the same way with every modern awk as it uses completely portable (and POSIX defined) constructs. From what I can see it WILL produce the posted output from the given sample input (except 2 trailing `*`s have disappeared but maybe the OP edited the question after this answer was posted) so if it's not producing the expected output then there is something about your input file that is different from the posted example.

Comment: @anubhava The awk script works fine except the case where there is anyother word having  "_" comes before the symbol.  eg Consider this line in the log abc_Def.obj : error unresolved symbol _xxxx.  The script prints Def.obj in that case. Also it is removing the _.

Comment: can you edit your question and provide sample input data. Also show your expected output for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If your grep supports -P then you could use the below regex.

```
grep -oP 'external symbol\K\h_\S+' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using (G)awk

```
awk 'match($0,/_([^*]+)/,a){print a[1]}' file
```

This would work if it had to be the next word after external symbol

```
awk 'match($0,/external symbol[^[:alnum:]]+([[:alnum:]]+)/,a){print a[1]}' file
```

Also as you have specified what a `word` constitutes of you could do this to include the `@`

```
awk 'match($0,/external symbol[^[:alnum:]]+([[:alnum:]@]+)/,a){print a[1]}' file
```

Comment: It works but its not true to: `Print the first word per line after "external symbol"`. It just happens to be after in this case.

Comment: It said in the second bit that that was just one way of trying to get the word after the _. I'll add one for that aswell though in a minute :)

Answer (score 0):

Another `gnu awk` (due to multiple characters in `RS`)

```
awk -v RS='external symbol \\*\\*_' -F'\\*\\*' 'NR>1{print $1}' file
DirectSoundCaptureEnumerateW@8
DSDEVID_DefaultVoiceCapture
IID_IDirectSoundCapture
DirectSoundCreate@12
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay try this:

`sed  's/[^_]*\( _[^\b\t\s ]*\)[^_]*/\1XXX/;s/\(.*\)XXX.*/\1/;s/.*\(_\)/\1/' logs_data`

```
It says 
[^_]* don't match _ any amount 
\( start a hold pattern 
_ start with underbar and terminate at any boundary \b or tab \t or space \s  
end hold \) 
[^_]* don't match _ any amount 
then replace the previous with a boundary marker XXX 
and delete everything else - keeping only the first match.
```

Comment: This doesn't work as head -1 returns only 1st result.